# Consumir json Retrofit no meu disposito real (smartphone)

Tags: android, json, retrofit, emulador

Fiz uma apirest com o Springboot que funciona perfeitamente pelo navegador no endereço.

```
http://localhost:8080/pessoas_escalas
```

Consigo consumir o serviço localmente pelo emulador do Android Studio, por meio do endereço configurado no Retrofit.

```
.baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
```

Nesse sentido, gostaria de ler o Json que está localmente, pelo meu dispositivo real(smartphone). Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executa o `ipconfig` na sua máquina e pega o ip. Em seguida, usa o seu ip e porta no seu código com retrofit para consumir.

Chamada do Retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("http://192.168.25.10:8080/pessoas_escalas")
.build();
```